# Why can't I create an instance of a new class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, model-view-controller

Task Controller

```
def new
    @task = Task.new
    @client = User.find(1).clients.find(1)
  end
  def create
    @task = Task.new
    @client = User.find(1).clients.find(1)
    @task.client_id = @client.id
    if @task.save
      puts "Task saved successfully"
    else
      puts "Task didn't save"
    end
  end
end
```

Task Model

```
  belongs_to :client
```

Client Model

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bots
  has_many :tasks
  attr_accessor :connection, :logs_enabled
  attr_writer :lonJS, :latJS
end
```

When I try and create a new instance of task it saves as nil. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "saves as nil"? Do you mean it saves a record where all fields are nil, including the `client_id`? As an aside, note that `@client = User.find(1).clients.find(1)`... each `find(1)` is finding the item that has an id specifically = 1. `User.find(1)` tries to find a client belonging to user id 1 that itself also has an id of 1. It may or may not exist. Since you didn't get an exception, I assume it did. So then `@task.client_id = @client.id` is really `@task.client_id = 1` in that context. Not sure what your intention really is here.

Comment: what error you get if you replace `@task.save` with `@task.save!`?

Comment: the problem seems to be in rails c. it turns out that classes are saving as nil

Comment: by saves as nil I mean that all attributes of a class result as nil when inputing Task.create

Comment: try 'save!' you will get a exception I think!!!

Comment: All attributes are nil because you haven't set anything while creating instance `Task.new`

Comment: Even if task id = nil

Comment: @JonathanPein the task only gets its `id` once you save the task.